# Creating a multiplication table inside turtle graphics - coding not working correctly

Tags: python, multiplication, turtle-graphics

I have been trying to create a program that display a multiplication table, exactly like this.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I am experiencing many problems with my coding. When I run the program as is now, this is what it looks like:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Here is the code I have:

```
import turtle

turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.penup()

turtle.write(("   Multiplication Table"), font =("Arial",20,"bold"))

for dash in range(-13, 250, 5):
    turtle.goto(dash, -40)
    turtle.write(("  -  "), font =("Arial", 10, "bold"))

j = 1 

for topFactor in range( 15, 240, 28):

    turtle.goto( topFactor, -30)

    turtle.write( str( j )+ "   |",font=("Arial",10,"bold"))

    j +=1

l = 1 

for rightFactor in range( 50, 240, 22):

    turtle.goto( -10, -rightFactor)

    turtle.write( str( l )+ "   |",font=("Arial",10,"bold"))

    l +=1 

    for topFactor in range(15, 240, 28):

        turtle.goto( topFactor, -50)

        turtle.write( str(l * j), font=("Arial",10,"bold"))

turtle.done()
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4):

This line is what keeps the numbers from populating the whole table:

```
turtle.goto( topFactor, -50)
```

it should be:

```
turtle.goto(topFactor, -rightFactor)
```

Also, your calculation of `l * j` is off because `j` isn't incrementing with the column at this point in the code.  Here's a potential rework:

```
import turtle

turtle.hideturtle()

turtle.penup()

turtle.write(("   Multiplication Table"), font = ("Arial", 20," bold"))

for dash in range(-13, 250, 5):
    turtle.goto(dash, -40)
    turtle.write(("  -  "), font = ("Arial", 10, "bold"))

for j, topFactor in enumerate(range(15, 240, 28)):

    turtle.goto(topFactor, -30)

    turtle.write(str(j + 1) + "   |", font = ("Arial", 10, "bold"))

for l, rightFactor in enumerate(range(50, 240, 22)):

    turtle.goto(-10, -rightFactor)

    turtle.write(str(l + 1) + "   |", font = ("Arial", 10, "bold")) 

    for j, topFactor in enumerate(range(15, 240, 28)):

        turtle.goto(topFactor, -rightFactor)

        turtle.write(str((l + 1) * (j + 1)), font = ("Arial", 10, "bold"))

turtle.done()
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. That makes sense. There were many things I did not do correctly.  You also did a really nice job cleaning the look of the program. Thanks dude!